# dynamically set text in textView android

Tags: android, radio-button, android-spinner, radio-group

I have radio button group and spinner in my android activity.First, I choose a radio button, then I choose spinner item. I want to see selected spinner item in textView. However, when I change spinner item, textView does not update. It updates only when I change radio button. How can I update textView dynamically? I am trying to product my radio button and spinner and display on textView.

```
public class GenelBagis extends AppCompatActivity  {
    Spinner spinnerGenelBagis;
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterForGenelBagis;
    String[] aylar;
    TextView mText;
    int amount=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_genel_bagis);

        aylar = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.month);
        spinnerGenelBagis = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        dataAdapterForGenelBagis = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,aylar);
        spinnerGenelBagis.setAdapter(dataAdapterForGenelBagis);
        mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView16);






        spinnerGenelBagis.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    RadioButton meslekLisesiButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.meslekLisesi);
                    RadioButton yuksekOgrenimButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.yuksekOgrenim);
                    RadioButton yuksekLisansButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.meslekLisesi);
                    RadioButton doktoraButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.meslekLisesi);

                String text = spinnerGenelBagis.getSelectedItem().toString();
                int month = Integer.parseInt(text);

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {



                        if (meslekLisesiButton.isChecked() == true) {
                           String amount = Integer.toString(month * 200);
                           mText.setText(amount);
                        } else if (yuksekOgrenimButton.isChecked() == true) {
                            //
                        } else if (yuksekLisansButton.isChecked() == true) {
                            //
                        } else if (doktoraButton.isChecked() == true) {
                            //

                        }

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });




    }}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.merve.tev.GenelBagis"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="Burs Vermek İstediğiniz Toplam Tutar"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner2"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="279dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:checkedButton="@+id/meslekLisesi"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="92dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/meslekLisesi"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Meslek Lisesi (Aylık) 200 TL" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/yuksekOgrenim"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Yüksek Öğrenim (Aylık) 510 TL"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="42dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="169dp" />



        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/yuksekLisans"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Yüksek Lisans (Aylık) 850 TL" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/doktora"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Doktora (Aylık) 1150 TL" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView15"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/devamEt2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Devam Et"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textView16"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView16" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Öğrenci Eğitim Düzeyine Göre Bağış"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kaç Aylık Burs Vermek İstersiniz?"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="89dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/devamEt2"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner2"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My activity looks like this:
[image: activity]

Comment: you are setting text inside the onCheckedChanged that's why it is setting after toggling radio button. Just Set text Inside onItemSelected and outside the onCheckedChanged. If you are checking some condition check it there.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I edited my question. I tried your solution, but it does not update. @RajatN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've totally changed the approach. Have a look.

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {
 Spinner spinnerGenelBagis;
 RadioGroup radioGroup;
 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterForGenelBagis;
 String[] aylar;
 TextView mText;

 private static int spinnerValue = 0;
 private static int radioValue = 0;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_genel_bagis);

    aylar = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.month);
    spinnerGenelBagis = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    dataAdapterForGenelBagis = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, aylar);
    spinnerGenelBagis.setAdapter(dataAdapterForGenelBagis);
    mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {


            if (checkedId == R.id.meslekLisesi) {

                radioValue = 200;
                updateTextView();

            } else if (checkedId == R.id.yuksekOgrenim) {

                radioValue = 300;
                updateTextView();

            } else if (checkedId == R.id.yuksekLisans) {
                //
            } else if (checkedId == R.id.doktora) {
                //

            }

        }
    });

    spinnerGenelBagis.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            String text = spinnerGenelBagis.getSelectedItem().toString();
            spinnerValue = Integer.parseInt(text);
            updateTextView();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}

private void updateTextView() {
    String totalAmount = Integer.toString(spinnerValue * radioValue);
    mText.setText(totalAmount);
}
```

}

Hope it helps.
And, you don't need to write `yuksekOgrenimButton.isChecked() = true` if you used it. `yuksekOgrenimButton.isChecked()` returns boolean by itself.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. If I change spinner item second time (I don't change radio button) , textView doesn't update.

Comment: Thanks for your response! It didn't work for me. Before, If I change radio button, textView updates. If I change spinner item (do not change button), textView doesn't updates. However now, it displays only 200. It doesn't change in any combination.

Comment: I'm still unclear about the situation. Do you want the total amount to change every time the different radio buttons or spinner item is selected?

Comment: Radio button corresponds to money and spinner item corresponds to a month. Therefore, I want to change total amount for both of change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155003/discussion-between-journey-and-heyaa).